# True or false or not-defined statements

Tags: logic

Is it correct to say that for a statement to be either true or false it has to be well defined?

For example: the statement 
$$\frac{1}{0} = 1$$
is neither true nor false because the expression on the left simply isn't defined.

Or the statement:

```
sdfjinrivodinvr
```

is not true or false because it doesn't make sense.

Or are these "expressions" even statements if they are not well-defined?

Comment: Your first expression *is* false, because the right-hand side *is* defined, and so if it were true then the left-hand side would also be defined. Your second statement is not a mathematical problem.

Comment: Your first example is false. Something you are comparing something well defined with something undefined by way of the equivalence relation =. The relation holds if and only if 1 and 1/0 are equivalent, which they are not.

Comment: The question reminds me of Pauli's remark: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong

Comment: @CliveN.: So would then also the statement $\frac{1}{0} = \frac{2}{0}$ be false? (here both sides not being well-defined)

Comment: @Thomas: I guess that would depend what you meant by each side of the equation. On a more formal level, if you have an interpretation of a logical system then you can only declare some formula $\phi$ in that system to be true or false if $\phi$ is actually a valid formula. So if $\phi$ is not then the truth or falsity (or otherwise) of $\phi$ is meaningless.

Comment: @CliveN.  Would "$1/0 \ne 1$" also be false for the same reason?  Or is the equality relation special?

Comment: @TrevorWilson: As above, I guess.

Comment: @CliveN.: That was what I was trying to ask. So I guess in my mind the $\frac{1}{0} = 1$ isn't true or false because it is not a valid formula since dividing by $0$ "isn't allowed".

Comment: @Thomas: Perhaps! It all depends on whether $\frac{1}{0}$ is a constant in your language ;)

Comment: How come all the debate is focusing on the first question?  I want to know if sdfjinrivodinvr is true!

Comment: The division "operation" in unpleasant to try to accommodate in a formal system. For when we are defining **term**, we cannot say that if $a$ and $b$ are terms, then $a\div b$ is a term. There are workarounds, but nothing direct.

Comment: How can a meaningless expression have truth or falsity?

Comment: Things get complicated. For example, in school mathematics, it is said that the "identity" $\frac{\sin(2x)}{\sin x}=2\cos x$ is called true even though the left side is undefined when $x$ is a multiple of $\pi$, while the right side is always defined.

Comment: related: [Does “This is a lie” prove the insufficiency of binary logic?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/119639/163)

Comment: My answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195952/propositional-calculus-and-lazy-evaluation/197241#197241) describes various ways of dealing formally with formulas like this.

Comment: My answers are [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4772282/21813) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4686405/21813).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematics is not the study of bits of ink on paper (or pixels on screens, indeed), it is the study of concepts and abstract ideas. Hence, when you look at some ink on a piece of paper, you have to first decide "does this correspond to an abstract idea?" before asking "what mathematical meaning does that idea contain?". Before you ask if $\frac{1}{0}=1$ is true or false, you need to ask what those symbols mean. Well, usually you *don't* need to ask, because it's obvious, but when you're unsure you ought to remember that just because you wrote down a thing, doesn't mean there's anything *in* it.

Hence I would argue that (unless you give meaning to it, and there is no "obvious" meaning in this case) $\frac{1}{0}=1$ is neither true nor false, because truth or falsity is a property of abstract mathematical concepts, and this pattern of pixels does not map to any such thing.

In programming terminology, I would describe it as a compile error, or a parse failure :)

Answer (score 9):

One way to make precise the distinction you're trying to make is the notion of a [well-formed formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula) in logic. Roughly speaking this is a formula which is built up from other formulas in a meaningful way, so it can be assigned some kind of meaning and it is meaningful to talk about whether or not it is true. A formula which is not well-formed does not in any meaningful sense have a truth value.

In a suitable formal system for talking about arithmetic operations, the expression $\frac{1}{0}$ is already not well-formed; division $\frac{a}{b}$ should only be well-formed if $b \neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So just to make sure that I understand, you would say that the first statement isn't true or false because it is not a well-formed formula, right?

Comment: @Thomas: yes, that's one interpretation. It is possible to give other interpretations to the symbol $\frac{1}{0}$ (for example in projective geometry) such that it is well-defined, and then it is just not equal to $1$.

Comment: I don't think this can be described as a well-formedness condition, because $\frac 1x$ certainly _is_ a well-formed term, and we're then going to need _some_ convention about what it means when $x$ is $0$. In principle one could decide never to allow the term $\frac 1x$ except in contexts where it can be _proved_ that $x\ne 0$, but that would be very far from the _syntactic_ character I would expect of the word "well-formed". (...)

Comment: (...) Letting provability intrude on well-formedness in this way would also mean that we could never speak about the meaning of formulas _themselves_ without reference to a proof system, which would make it difficult even to formulate soundness and completeness properties for a proof system.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: in the formalism *I* know, division isn't an operation, it's just shorthand for multiplication by inverse, and it is a theorem that (in a field) an inverse always exists except if you are zero. There's then a subtlety as to how you translate formulae involving division into something valid... I might edit my answer with my thoughts on this.

Comment: I'm not going to edit my answer, but it's now too late to edit my comment. In any case, it occurs that you could interpret the statement as either an exists (there's an inverse of zero, and this formula is true about it) or a forall (for any inverse of zero, this formula is true about it) and you get false and true respectively.

Comment: @Ben: I don't think division vs inverse is the real problem here; in my comments you can consider "$\frac{1}{\ldots}$" to be a monolithic symbol for "inverse of ...", and my points would be no more or less valid for that.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: but the point is that "inverse of" isn't a syntactic operation, it is instead a theorem that inverses exist most of the time. If anything, we can say that "x is an inverse of y" is a binary relation symbol: now if we try to recast the expression given in terms of that relation, we run into the forall-or-exists choice.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Dr. Makholm: I asked a follow-up question and I would appreciate your input. Thanks. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201431/frac1x-1-for-all-real-numbers-x-is-not-true-or-false

Comment: @Thomas: Your excellency, I don't think I have much to add beyond what I said [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195952/propositional-calculus-and-lazy-evaluation/197241#197241).

Answer (score 7):

If a statement does not make sense, it is neither false nor true. As Pauli said, it's not even wrong.

Comment: Strange though it may seem, have an upvote!

Answer (score 4):

The statement $1/0=1$ could reasonably be construed as meaning that the expression to the left of "$=$" *is* defined, and its numerical value is $1$.  And that is certainly false.

While in high school Jubal Harshaw won a debate by citing the British Colonial Shipping Board as the authority supporting some factual statement.  But the British Colonial Shipping Board never existed; he made it up.  Is his assertion false, or just meaningless?

(Some may know that Jubal Harshaw himself is a character in a novel that has a legal notice in its front matter, saying all persons in this story are fictitious.  So one might wonder whether my assertion about what Jubal Harshaw did is true or false.)

Comment: Interesting. I had actually thought of an analogy to my question along those lines. It is kind of like asking questions that do not have answers because they assume things that are not true. If one asks for the reason why the sky is green, then that question isn't well-defined because it assumes something that is false.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the original question of the author remains still unanswered - are there such mathematical statements that are well-formed and understandable, but still are not true or false? We have been focusing too much on the examples.

First of all, there are such statements which have not been proven true or false, but could, given enough time and a smart brain. For instance prime number theory - whether given large number is a prime or not, can not be proven true or false at a moment (without testing all the candidates) but possibly could be in the future.

Then there are statements that can not be proven, and the fact that they can not be proven has been proved. For instance:

http://www.edge.org/q2005/q05_9.html#dysonf

So the answer is YES.

Comment: *Any* statement can be proven, if we take a sufficiently strong set of axioms - particularly if we take the statement itself as an axiom.  There are results of the form "statement $X$ is not provable in the specific system $Y$" but these cannot be summarized as "$X$ cannot be proven".